# Don't know how to wait for the Coordinates data to resolve, so i can GET data from Openweather

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, navigator

So the idea behind is that when the Site loads, it displays the current temperature of my location using geolocation Object.
Now I don't really understand how async and await functions work and less how observables work.

My code works when I define a fixed lat and lon, but not when I try to get it from the geolocation.

So here is the service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, map } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from '../interfaces/user.interface';
import { Current } from '../interfaces/current.interface';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WeatherService {

  private api : string = '1a090ef1bd211e03abf218229fd62e55';
  private url : string = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather';
  private settings! : User;

  public setWeather(lat : number, lon : number, unit : string, location : string){
    this.settings = {lat : lat, lon : lon, units : unit, location : location};
  }

  private buildUrl(): string{
    return`${this.url}?lat=${this.settings.lat}&lon=${this.settings.lon}&appid=${this.api}&units=${this.settings.units}`;
  }

  public getCurrentWeather$(): Observable<Current>{

    return this.http.get<any>(this.buildUrl())
    .pipe(map((res) =>{
      const Current : Current = {
        location : res.name,
        temperature : res.main.temp,
        wind : res.wind,
        description : res.weather[0].description,
        icon : res.weather[0].main,
        time : res.dt
      }
      return Current;
    }));
  }
  constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) { }
}
```

and here is my component:

```
import { IconService } from './../../shares/services/icon.service';
import { Current } from './../../shares/interfaces/current.interface';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { take} from 'rxjs';
import { WeatherService } from 'src/app/shares/services/weather.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-start',
  templateUrl: './start.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./start.component.scss']
})
export class StartComponent implements OnInit {

  public Current : Current | undefined;

  constructor(private readonly weatherService : WeatherService, private readonly iconService : IconService) {
    if(navigator.geolocation){
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((pos)=>{
        return this.weatherService.setWeather(pos.coords.latitude,pos.coords.longitude,'metric','');
      })
    }
  }

 ngOnInit():void {
    this.weatherService.getCurrentWeather$()
    .pipe(take(1))
    .subscribe((data) =>{
      this.Current = data;
      this.Current.icon = this.iconService.getIcon(this.Current.description);
      return this.Current
    })
  }
```

I have tried to put the function, that returns the new URL with the current location inside the observable, but with the same error (property of 'lat' not found).
Now in the code above the code for the geolocation is in the constructor of the component and sends the same error

> main.ts:11 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'lat').

Comment: Seems like you should get the weather in the callback of `getCurrentPosition` after the call to `setWeather` so that you know `settings` is set, rather than in `ngOnInit` which can happen at any point after the constructor of the component.